# Удалять файлы с сортировкой по времени не больше определённого кол-ва

Tags: linux, bash

Я знаю, что можно удалять старые файлы (старше одного дня) просто командой `find /my/path/ -mtime +1 -type f -exec rm  {}  \;` , а можно ли как-то удалять в директории `/my/path/` файлы старше одного дня, но только, если их (файлов) там больше, ну, например, 10-ти? А точнее даже так: удалять в директории `/my/path/` файлы, но всегда оставлять 10 самых новых.

Не могу найти простого способа :( Пока вижу длинный и сложный (для меня) способ с сортировкой по `ls -lsht`, условием `if ... > 10` и удалением в цикле...

Comment: сортировать файлы (по любому признаку) программа *find* не обучена. используйте программы *ls* + *head/tail* + *rm* (если в конвейере, то + *xargs*)

Comment: ну и вопрос, конечно, неясен, так как содержит взаимоисключающие под-вопросы. [edit]

Comment: Я бы на питоне скрипт написал, вместо того чтобы пайпожуть городить

Answer (score 3):

GNU find умеет выводить дату в секундах с 1970года, сортировку по дате поручим sort -n, cut вырежет первый столбец после сортировки, отбрасывать первые 10 строк умеет tail. Удалять махом много файлов умеет rm + xargs. Если список файлов на удаление пустой - команду rm не запускаем.
Все вместе получается вот так:

```
find /my/path/ -type f -mtime +1 -printf "%A@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d" " -f 2 | tail -n "+10" | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

То же самое, разделенное по строкам для простоты восприятия:

```
find /my/path/ -type f -mtime +1 -printf "%A@ %p\n" \
| sort -n \
| cut -d" " -f 2 \
| tail -n "+10" \
| xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

То же самое, но pipe покороче (объединение cut и tail в sed):

```
find /my/path/ -type f -mtime +1 -printf "%A@ %p\n" \
| sort -n \
| sed -rn '10,$s|^[^ ]* (.*$)|\1|p' \
| xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

Comment: А это так и задумано, что `ls -1t ` выполняется для текущей директории, а не для вывода из предыдущей команды через пайп? :)

Comment: Дорогой @nobody, вариант изначально предложенный в ответе неточный и предполагал вот такое `find /my/path/ -type f -mtime +1 | xargs ls -1t | tail -n "+10" | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm`, но при большом числе файлов будет работать неверно.
Спасибо за критику, ответ исправил. Убрал ls, сделал через sort.